# Object spark is not a member of package org

Tags: scala, apache-spark, sbt, scala-ide

When importing the following in Eclipse Scala-IDE

```
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext._
```

I get this error: 
`Object spark is not a member of package org`

I installed the sbt-0.13.9.msi

What else should I do?

build.sbt

```
name := "scala-spark-app"

version := "1.0"

scalaVersion := "2.10.4"

libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % "1.5.2"
```

Comment: How did you create this project? Does the problem exist when you simply run `sbt package`?

Comment: It the error message literally "Object spark is not a member of package org"? Did you maybe somewhere type `org.spark` instead of `org.apache.spark`?

Comment: C:\Users\Adham>sbt package
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=256m; support was removed in 8.0
[info] Set current project to adham (in build file:/C:/Users/Adham/)
[success] Total time: 0 s, completed 27-Nov-2015 19:10:51

Comment: Why it is so complicated to use/setup Scala, setting  up Java is very easy, just install eclipse and the JDK and you are done!

Comment: Are you on mac or linux? Go to your project directory (where your build.sbt file lives), type `sbt compile`. Does everything work ok?

Comment: Compling succeed but when I ran the .scala file I still get problems  
 C:\Users\Adham\ScalaWorkSpace\Chapter1>sbt compile
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=256m; support was removed in 8.0
[info] Set current project to scala-spark-app (in build file:/C:/Users/Adham/ScalaWorkSpace/Chapter1/)
[success] Total time: 5 s, completed 30-Nov-2015 12:25:30

Comment: in linux: adhem@adhem-ThinkPad-E520:~/workspace/Chapter1$ sbt compile
[info] Loading project definition from /home/adhem/workspace/Chapter1/project/project
[info] Loading project definition from /home/adhem/workspace/Chapter1/project
[info] Set current project to scala-spark-app (in build file:/home/adhem/workspace/Chapter1/)
[success] Total time: 0 s, completed Dec 1, 2015 11:13:39 PM

Comment: in windows and in linux the problem is the same!

Answer (score 3):

I was receiving the same compilation error (on my Mac) with IntelliJ whereas `sbt compile` executed successfully. The following steps solved my problem:

1. sbt clean
2. sbt [gen-idea](https://github.com/mpeltonen/sbt-idea) (to rebuild IntelliJ project files)
3. quit and restart IntelliJ

I hope this helps.

Comment: THis question is for Eclipse Scala-IDE and not IntelliJ